# Entity Framework Migrations - Seed runs even if no migration?

Tags: entity-framework, database-migration

I have set up a simple Migration with `AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false`. Everything works great from visual studio or when using `MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion`.

However, this is not ideal for me. I would like to run migrations from a deployment script on my ci server. I found [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj618307.aspx) explaining how to do this using migrate.exe **but** this seems to **always** run the seed. This is even when there are no migrations to apply.

Do I need to check programmatically within the Seed method whether any migrations have been run? How do I do this?

Comment: Why not make your seed idempotent?

Comment: @LukeMcGregor - If I want to insert some data how would I do that without explicitly hard-coding keys or running custom written checks on each table for upsorts?

Comment: personally i hard-code keys for seed data, given its seed its static anyway IMO

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [DbMigrator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.migrations.dbmigrator%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) to manually run Update() only if there are pending migrations. It was introduced in Entity Framework 5.0.

```
private void MigrateAndSeedDbIfSchemaIsOutdated()
{
    // Disable initializer.
    Database.SetInitializer<MyContext>(null);

    // Make sure database exists.
    using (var db = new MyContext())
    {
        db.Database.Initialize(false);
    }

    var migrator = new DbMigrator(new MyConfiguration());

    if (migrator.GetPendingMigrations().Any())
    {
        // Run migrations and seed.
        migrator.Update();
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, didn't know about that method thanks! A note on your LINQ - there is no need to call `ToList` here, you can simply leave pendingMigrations as an `IEnumerable<>` and call `.Any()` on that. Calling `ToList` forces the entire enumeration to evaluate whereas you only care about whether there is at least one  item in it.

Comment: You are right, I used that part for debugging. I've edited the answer.